# Strange NullReferenceException when using ServiceStack.OrmLite async API

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, ormlite-servicestack

I keep getting a NullReferenceException when using ServiceStack.ORMLite's async API. I don't really know where to go from here and I have to admit I'm going half insane

What I know is that switching `await db.SelectAsync<T>(sqlString, parameters);` for `db.Select<T>(sqlString, parameters);` resolves the problem.

Tasks

[image: Tasks]

The stacktrace

```
   at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__18_0(Object s)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```